# python write lines to file avoid the newline at end of file

Tags: python, text

I am processing text files with python under windows, some contents of source files like this:

---

```
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  1346    S000009106  BC14D01137      0   788 0   0   0   788 
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  1425    S000009107  BC14D01587      0   1088    0   0   0   1088    
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  1425    S000009107  BC14D99998      0   -8468   0   0   0   -8468   
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  1425    S000009107  BC14D02045      0   3690    0   0   0   3690    
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  1425    S000009107  BC14D02087      0   3690    0   0   0   3690    
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  1702    S000009108  BC14D01900      0   1690    0   0   0   1690    
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  1702    S000009108  BC14D02106      0   4690    0   0   0   4690    

FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  1702    S000009108  BC14D00653      0   1680    0   0   0   1680    
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  1702    S000009108  BC14D99996      0   -10000  0   0   0   -10000  
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  1702    S000009108  BC14D99996      0   10000   0   0   0   10000   

FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  1702    S000009108  BC14D01601      0   228 0   0   0   228 
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  1702    S000009108  BC14D99998      0   -5968   0   0   0   -5968   
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  1702    S000009108  BC14D02046      0   3990    0   0   0   3990    
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  1702    S000009108  BC14D02045      0   3690    0   0   0   3690    

FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  2041    S000009109  BC14D01721      0   1183    0   0   0   1183    
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  2041    S000009109  BC14D01892      0   903 0   0   0   903 
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  2121    S000009110  BC14D02114      0   16900   0   0   0   16900   
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  2121    S000009110  BC14D01898      0   256 0   0   0   256 
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  2121    S000009110  BC14D99998      0   -7284   0   0   0   -7284   

FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  2121    S000009110  BC14D99997      0   5000    0   0   0   5000    
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  2121    S000009110  BC14D99996      0   -10000  0   0   0   -10000  
FSZHB1  04  2012-11-24  2121    S000009110  BC14D01652      0   128 0   0   0   128
```

I will remove all blank lines with python codes:

---

```
def rem_blanklines(fings = None,c_path =None):
    if os.path.isfile(fings):
        tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir = c_path,delete = False)
        blank_p = re.compile('\S')
        with tf,open(fings) as f_obj:
            for fl in f_obj:
                if blank_p.match(fl):
                    fl = (fl.strip() + '\r\n').encode('UTF-8')
                    tf.write(fl)
        bakfile = fings + '.bak'
        os.rename(fings,bakfile)
        os.rename(tf.name,fings)
        os.remove(bakfile)

for x in os.listdir(wkd):
    xx = os.path.join(wkd,x)
    if os.path.isfile(xx):
        rem_blanklines(fings = xx,c_path = wkd)
```

my questions are:

1. there is a newline symbol at end of processed files,how can i avoid
   it?
2. i want to also remove the lines like this:

   - the fifth columns are equal
   - and the eighth columns the sum is equal to 0

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate "new line" entries at the end of sentences by ".rstrip()". There are plenty of tutorials on web about such string processing tools. "tutorialspoint.com" can be a good start.

If you are familiar with linux and able to integrate your code with a shell script, then you can use the built-in regex tool, "sed", for string detection and "awk" for easily dealing with columns.

If you are not, I recommend you to get familiar with it if there is nothing special about using windows in your work. In text processing, hybrid use of shell and python yields considerable advantages.